# Мультиязычный сайт WordPress с ACF

Tags: wordpress, acf

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать сайт мультиязычным? Какие плагины лучше всего подходят для этого, которые совместимы с ACF ?

Comment: Лучший - это WPML, он платный, но стоит того.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно хороший плагин.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что поиск библиотек, плагинов является оффтопиком на stackoverflow

Comment: @AK, а поиск решений? Решений, которые решаются плагинами. ака готовым кодом.

Answer (score 1):

Любые плагины для мультиязычности. 
Напр.

https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/
https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/